# Android : Branch SDK Api Error after changed date on device

Tags: android, branch.io

I try to apply branch.io link

After changed the date with device settings, for example, month before or after the current date; branch.io shows error: "Trouble initializing Branch. Branch API Error: poor network connectivity. Please try again later."

In the source code I see matching from "Trouble reaching server. Please try again in a few minutes" endpoint "v1/install"

If I return the correct date - everythink is ok

branch sdk version 4.3.2

How can I fix applying links with incorrect time?

Answer (score 0):

Branch does not allow the device time to be changed.This is done to maintain accuracy of attribution. If you try to change the device time, it causes the app itself to experience a CertPathValidatorException when it try's to reach the Branch servers.